# Custom option is broken my magento theme, how can i fix?

Tags: magento

when i add a custom option in my magento product, im using magento 1.7.02 my theme broken for some reason, i tried change something in the view.phtml (template/catalog/product) but without success...

i dont know where i can change there to fix, i tried change the position from the custom option, but nothing worked
Some ideas please?

[Product With Custom Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbJCf.gif)

[Product without Custom Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKhcB.jpg)

```
*the code in view.phtml 

<!-- AddThis Button END --> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: also, here is the link for the Without Custom Option http://www.boutiquekawaii.com/corsets/corset-test-169.html

Comment: and with custom option http://www.boutiquekawaii.com/corsets/corset-test.html

Answer (score 0):

I can see a solution for that two tabs `Product Description` and `Product tags` are showing well

open http://www.boutiquekawaii.com/corsets/corset-test.html
go to inspect by right click and select `Inspect`

Now down there in Elements tab search for this class `product-shop span8`
you will find a div like this

```
<div class="product-shop span8">
....
   <div class="clearer"></div> <!-- you need to move this -->
</div>
```

and in that div there is a div like this `<div class="clearer"></div>` which should not be there.That div should be after

like this

```
<div class="product-shop span8">
    ....
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div> <!-- and place it here before </form> tag -->
</form>
```

And you will have this result. Just like your other page.
[image: you will have result]

So open that file `template/catalog/product/view.phtml` find `<div class="clearer"></div>` and change it like i said.

Comment: Hello, thank you! but when i went to view.phtml is already like you said      <!-- AddThis Button END --> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearer"></div>
    </form>
  </div>

Comment: It is still there at the wrong place.See http://puu.sh/xMvVt/a6e13a93a4.jpg
Open `Inspect` search `product-shop span8` which is yellow colored in my image right click on it then select Edit as Html then scroll down at the end you will see that you can move it at the end to see the effect.

Comment: HI i did that on the inspect and works, but when i go to the phtml file look like that [link](https://ibb.co/ibnWiw)

Comment: Make sure you are doing changes in the right file because from the image in your file there is a </div> after `</form>` but in Inspect we can not see that. To be sure that you are in right file you can change `<!-- AddThis add some text here Button END -->` and see if it's coming in Inspect or not. And I can't check your file but if that is the correct file then `<!-- AddThis Button END -->` after this 3 div should finish and then `<div class="clearer"></div>`. Like this http://puu.sh/xNbeZ/0e139fe7e9.png

Comment: And don't forget to do this. In your admin panel Go to System ->> Cache Management Click on the “Flush Cache Storage” button to clear Cache.

Comment: Hello, thank you!! i added a third </div> as you told me and looks like it is working now, the product description went down but the gray box from product option still there behind the product price. I tried to move <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>   to another place, but for some reason duplicates the add to cart, do you have some ideas about this please?

Comment: if you just want to remove that gray color then go to `http://www.boutiquekawaii.com/skin/frontend/default/madame-modern/css/styles.css` open the styles.css file and line no. 819 or find this `.product-options {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 18px 0 0;
    /* border: 1px solid #EFEFEF; */
    /* background-color: #f7f7f7; */
}` 
and comment both line with `/* -- */`